# How to use Regex to show numbers ? (Android)

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this line:

```
stringer = str.replaceAll("[\\P{L}\\p{N}\\p{Latin}/u]", " ");
```

It replaces all Latin chars with space `(" ")` but it also replaces numeric symbols

And I don't want it to replace numeric symbols , what do I need to change in this line to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
stringer = str.replaceAll("[\\P{L}\\p{N}\\p{Latin}/u&&[^\\d]]", " ");
```

Comment: You're wellcome... Would you mind accepting the answer (by clicking the check mark next to the answer) then... :)

Comment: Be careful with \p{Latin} as it has limited implementation.

`Very few regular expression engines support Unicode scripts today. Of all the flavors discussed in this tutorial, only the JGsoft engine, Perl and PCRE can match Unicode scripts.`

[check here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the built in android normalizer which will convert them to their non-latin version.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer.html